# why data not recognized in model.matrix() in R?

Tags: r, function, regression, lm

I was wondering why in my function below where I use the base R dataset `CO2` with `Plant` as one of its data columns I get the following error:

`Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Plant' not found`

How to fix this problem?

```
pc <- function(data, ref.variable){

as.data.frame(model.matrix(ref.variable ~ ., data = data))
}

pc(data = CO2, ref.variable = Plant) # Gives Error

## NOTE: it works OK this way: model.matrix(Plant ~ ., data = CO2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to `paste` and then wrap with `formula`

```
pc <- function(data, ref.variable){

     as.data.frame(model.matrix(formula(paste0(ref.variable,  "~ .")), data = data))
 }

res <- pc(data = CO2, ref.variable = "Plant") 
head(res)
#  (Intercept) TypeMississippi Treatmentchilled conc uptake
#1           1               0                0   95   16.0
#2           1               0                0  175   30.4
#3           1               0                0  250   34.8
#4           1               0                0  350   37.2
#5           1               0                0  500   35.3
#6           1               0                0  675   39.2
```

---

If we need to pass the ref.variable as unquoted, then use `substitute` within the function

```
pc <- function(data, ref.variable){

  ref.variable <- substitute(ref.variable)

 as.data.frame(model.matrix(formula(paste0(ref.variable,  "~ .")), data = data))
 }

pc(data = CO2, ref.variable = Plant)
```

Comment: @rnorouzian  Looks, like you got an answer for that